# Write command to store tennis rally in memcached

Tags: memcached

Use Memcached to store the points of Roger Federer (referred as F) and Rafael Nadal (referred as N). The initial scores are 0-0.

***Unix command***

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install memcached

$ add F 1 0 1
  0
  STORED
$ add N 1 0 1
  0
  STORED
```

But it seems that is not exact solution.

No error message displayed

Answer (score 0):

Following commands worked for me. Please can you also try them .

```
add F 1 0 3
0-0
```

```
add N 1 0 3
0-0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the tennis rally problem below is the solution

add F 1 0 3
0-0
add N 1 0 3
0-0
set F 1 0 5
45-15
set N 1 0 5
45-15